# C++ program reports "Process terminated with status -1073741510"

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am doing a algorithm and data structure exercise in C++ which requires to read a ten-word txt file then display them in a reserved order by using a stack without STL, class or struct. All the code looks good but it display nothing when I actually run it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int mindex = -1;
string word[10];

void push(string p);
void top();
void pop();
bool isEmpty();
int main()
{
    string filename,eli;
    cout << "Please input a file name" << endl;
    cin>>filename;
    ifstream inData;
    inData>>eli;
    inData.open(filename);
    if (!inData)
    {
        cerr<< "Error opening : " << filename << endl;
        return -1;
     };
    while (inData >> eli)
    {
        if(inData.fail()){
            break;  }
        else push(eli);
    }
    while (!isEmpty()){
         top();
         pop();
        }
    inData.close();
    return 0;
}
  void push(string p){
      index++;
      word[mindex] = p;
  }
    void pop(){
      mindex--;
  }

    void top(){
        cout<<word[mindex]<<" ";
  }
    bool isEmpty(){
        return (mindex<0);
  }
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: `ifstream inData; inData>>eli; inData.open(filename);` You create a file stream, read from it and then you open it. What do you expect there to happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes and assumptions here that could go wrong. I will only focus on the immediately obvisous.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; // only for demos/slideware/toy projects.
int mindex = -1;
string word[10]; // we will only ever get 10 strings? 
                 // 10 is a magic number use a const like const int maxWords = 10;
                 // using std::array will catch problems like this, std::vector can be used to dynamically resize the array.

void push(string p);
void top();
void pop();
bool isEmpty();

int main() {
    string filename,eli;
    cout << "Please input a file name" << endl;
    cin>>filename;
    ifstream inData;
    inData>>eli; // reading from not open file!!!
    inData.open(filename);
    if (!inData) { 
        cerr<< "Error opening : " << filename << endl;
        return -1;
    };

    while (inData >> eli) {
        if(inData.fail()) {
            break;
        } else 
            push(eli);
    }

    while (!isEmpty()){
         top();
         pop();
    }

    inData.close();
    return 0;
}

void push(string p){
    index++; // did you mean mindex???
    word[mindex] = p; // fatal error if mindex is not at least 0.
}

void pop(){
  mindex--;
}

void top(){
    cout<<word[mindex]<<" ";
}

bool isEmpty(){
    return (mindex<0);
}
```

A check for mindex at/above 10 should be done somewhere unless you are absolutely sure there will never be more than 10 words.

Comment: What is wrong with my inData>>eli ?  Should i type it after inData.open(filename); ?

Comment: Im sure there are only ten words

Comment: @StevenLi the file is not open when you read form it first time.